# Angular 4 : get error message in subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

In the service, there is this code :

```
  getUser(id){
    return this.http.get('http:..../' + id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

In the component :

```
this.myService.getUser(this.id).subscribe((customer) => {
  console.log(customer);
  this.customer = customer,
  (err) => console.log(err)
});
```

When it's the 'customer' exist, no problem I get all the information about the customer.

When the id does not exist, the web api return 'BadRequest' with a message. How can I get this message ? the status ?

Thanks,

Comment: If error object is showing up in console then you can simply do `err._body` to get the message

Answer (score 70, accepted):

***Update (with RxJs 6.x.x & Angular v14+):***

Subscribing to service and capturing error response:

```
this.myService.getUser(this.id).subscribe({
  next: (customer) => {
    console.log(customer);
    this.customer = customer,
  }, error: (err) => {console.log(err)}
});
```

To get the error msg back, add a `catchError` pipe that will return the error object:

```
// import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
...

getUser(id){
  return this.http.get('http:..../' + id)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  return throwError(() => error);
}
```

***Original (with RxJs v5.x.x):***

`(err)` needs to be outside the `customer` fat arrow:

```
this.myService.getUser(this.id).subscribe((customer) => {
  console.log(customer);
  this.customer = customer,
},
(err) => {console.log(err)});
```

To get the error msg back, add a `catch` that will return the error object:

```
getUser(id){
  return this.http.get('http:..../' + id)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) { 
  let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Comment: and to get the message ?

Comment: Need a `catch` for that. Updated the answer :)

Comment: Does the error object show up in console? If it does, then you can simply do err._body inside the fat arrow to get access to the message.

Comment: now it is deprecated https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you call catch without using arrow function like below

```
getUserList() {
    return this.http.get(this.constURL + '/loans/all', this.headerOptions)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

handleError(error: Response) {
    if (error.status == 500) {      
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

then it gives error of

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined not getting this

Because in handleError function this object is not accessible..if you console this.router then you will get undefined..
so this object not working and not getting router all available methods

So you have to use arrow function here like below

```
getUserList() {
    return this.http.get(this.constURL + '/loans/all', this.headerOptions)
    .catch(error => { 
      return this.handleError(error);
    });
}

handleError(error: Response) {
    if (error.status == 500) {      
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

Also if you have not mentioned return for handlerError function then it will throw error again like

Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type

So its necessary to type return for handlerError function.

Check in details [here](http://musttoknows.com/angular-4-call-catch-callback-function-handle-error-manage-errors-get-post-services/) . He has explained code very well with all possible errors and solution of that..worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I asked my friend for help so he told : Well in the component place `err.error.message` like below >>

```
 this.myService.getUser(this.id).subscribe((customer) => {
  console.log(customer);
  this.customer = customer,
  (err) => console.log(err.error.message)
});
```

Comment: error.status >> return HTTP status code
error.error.message >> return service custom message

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is deprecated: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Here is for newer versions at the moment of this post:

```js
this.service.getFoo(ID).subscribe({
    next: (result) => {
        this.foo = result;
        /* ... */
    },

    error: (error) => {
        // throw error;
        throw error.message;
    },
})
```

Comment: Although valid point, it also depends on the version of RXJS in use

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `err.json()` in your callback parameters

```js
this.myService.getUser(this.id).subscribe((customer) => {
  console.log(customer);
  this.customer = customer,
  (err) => {
    const error_response = err.json(); // response body
    console.log(error_response)
  }
});
```